# Running the queue listener without access to command line

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I don't have access to command line on production web server so I cannot simply run `php artisan queue:listen` as I do locally.

I have tried running the command via route like this :

```
Route::get('start-queue-listener', function() {

    Artisan::call('queue:listen');

});
```

But page just keep on loading infinitely and queue messages are not processed.

Comment: If you don't have access to a shell probably the best thing would be to use https://github.com/JN-Jones/web-artisan

Comment: @Adrenaxus While **web-artisan** is a nice tool, it does essentially the same thing when it comes to `queue:listen`, because the command keeps the process running indefinitely by using a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: @Roatha Chann If you have access to some kind of server management web interface (such as cPanel), you could get around the problem by defining a **cron job** that runs the command. Other than that, you're out of luck. Also, are you by any chance working with a shared server?

Comment: The problem is that if you call the queue:listen via a web call - it will timeout. You have to call it via a command, so PHP wont timeout throughout Apache. As Bogdan said - you can trick this into running using a cron job to run the queue:listen once via the cron command.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have cPanel, you can use SSH Access.